# Syntax Highlighter with Code Documentation Pop Up

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-highlighting

Is there any javascript based Syntax Highlighter with Code Documentation Pop-Up. what I mean is when the cursor hover some tags or property it will show pop up screen with tag description.

Just like [Mozilla Thimble](https://thimble.webmaker.org/en-US/editor) , When you click on some HTML tags, or CSS properties, it will show pop up help with description of code.
[image]

Comment: Well, I hear there's this project called Mozilla Thimble...  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like ACE editor - http://ace.ajax.org/ - and then override the editor click event.